# Alguien tiene idea de cómo lograr que el menú me quede en una columna, y el título, subtítulo, y cuerpo me queden en otra?

Tags: html, css, table

```css
P {
font-weight : normal;
text-align : justify;
}
H1 {
text-align : center-left;
}
BODY {
font-family : "Lucida Sans Unicode";
width : 900px;
margin : auto;
}
#menu {
    float : left;
    width : 100px;
}
table, tr {
    border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <!-- enlazo la hoja de estilo -->
  <link rel="STYLESHEET" type="text/css" href="css/hoja de estilo.css">
  <title>Parque Natural Sierra Bicuerca - Bienvenidos</title> 
<style>
h1{
    color:#18BF70;  
    }
h1 span {
    color:#D47640;  
    }
h2{
    color:#65CF47;  
    }
body {
font-family:"Lucida Sans Unicode";
}
</style>
</head>
<body> 
<h1>Parque Natural <span>Sierra Bicuerca</span></h1>

<ul id="menu">
  <li><a href="index.html">Inicio</a></li>
  <li><a href="especies.html">Especies</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Reservas</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Galer&iacute;a</a></li>
</ul>

<div>
<table>
<tr>
<h2>Bienvenidos al Parque Natural</h2>
</tr>

<tr>
<p>El Parque Natural de Sierra Bicuerca, reserva de la biosfera, es referencia obligada del bosque y matorral mediterr&aacute;neo interior, y h&aacute;bitat de la fauna y flora aut&oacute;ctona.</p>
<p>Fue declarado parque natural en 1983, con una superficie de 9.090 Has. siendo uno de los enclaves m&aacute;s extensos de la Comunidad Valenciana. Con un gran espesor de vegetaci&oacute;n, y varios riachuelos ofrecen un clima ideal para las especies terrestres y acu&aacute;ticas. Sus bosques, de carrasca y pino, albergan una amplia colonia de aves.</p>
<p>Entre las especies del parque podemos destacar una de las &uacute;ltimas colonias de buitre leonado de la zona. Tambi&eacute;n nos veremos constantemente sobrevolados por el halc&oacute;n peregrino o el &aacute;guila perdicera. Al acercarnos a los riachuelos, veremos numerosas pisadas de jabal&iacute;s y ciervos, y si no hacemos mucho ruido, no es dif&iacute;cil encontrar alguno abrevando bajo la atenta mirada del mart&iacute;n pescador, esperando a la despistada trucha.</p>
</tr>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

No sé me ocurre como hacer una tabla en la que me quede en una columna, el menú que tiene los diferentes items, y en otra el título, subtítulo y el cuerpo.⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀

Answer (score 1):

Primero que nada te recomiendo dejar de lado el uso de la propiedad `float` de css, ya está en desuso, por otro lado no es necesario usar table para posicionar elementos, ya que puedes hacerlo con la propiedad `flex` de css, evita usar css que el body que podrías aplicar de mejor forma a un contenedor con los elementos que quieres manipular.

El orden de los elementos en css es en cascada, lo que significa que el orden de los elementos es importante para la correcta carga y tiempo de carga del sitio. (No escribas nombres de etiquetas en mayúsculas).

creo que lo siguiente te puede ayudar, solo restaría que juegues con un poco de padding para ordenar los elementos.

```css
body {
  font-family : "Lucida Sans Unicode";
}
.container {
  display: flex; /* posiciona contenedores en fila */
  width : 900px;
  margin : auto;
}
h1 {
  text-align: center-left;
  color:#18BF70;
}
h1 span {
  color:#D47640;  
}
h2{
  color:#65CF47;  
}
p {
  text-align: justify;
}
#menu {
  width : 100px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <!-- enlazo la hoja de estilo -->
  <link rel="STYLESHEET" type="text/css" href="css/hoja de estilo.css">
  <title>Parque Natural Sierra Bicuerca - Bienvenidos</title> 
</head>
<body> 

<div class="container">
  <ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="index.html">Inicio</a></li>
    <li><a href="especies.html">Especies</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Reservas</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Galer&iacute;a</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div>
    <h1>Parque Natural <span>Sierra Bicuerca</span></h1>
    <h2>Bienvenidos al Parque Natural</h2>

    <p>El Parque Natural de Sierra Bicuerca, reserva de la biosfera, es referencia obligada del bosque y matorral mediterr&aacute;neo interior, y h&aacute;bitat de la fauna y flora aut&oacute;ctona.</p>
    <p>Fue declarado parque natural en 1983, con una superficie de 9.090 Has. siendo uno de los enclaves m&aacute;s extensos de la Comunidad Valenciana. Con un gran espesor de vegetaci&oacute;n, y varios riachuelos ofrecen un clima ideal para las especies terrestres y acu&aacute;ticas. Sus bosques, de carrasca y pino, albergan una amplia colonia de aves.</p>
    <p>Entre las especies del parque podemos destacar una de las &uacute;ltimas colonias de buitre leonado de la zona. Tambi&eacute;n nos veremos constantemente sobrevolados por el halc&oacute;n peregrino o el &aacute;guila perdicera. Al acercarnos a los riachuelos, veremos numerosas pisadas de jabal&iacute;s y ciervos, y si no hacemos mucho ruido, no es dif&iacute;cil encontrar alguno abrevando bajo la atenta mirada del mart&iacute;n pescador, esperando a la despistada trucha.</p>

  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```